# How to recover Chrome history, bookmarks, session on linux after everything was erased (also from Google servers)

Tags: linux, data-recovery, chromium

After upgrading chrome I lost everything. In an attempt to get things back I tried 'syncing' with Google, but to make a long story short I ended up erasing *everything* - from both the Google servers as well as my local files.

The question is: how to recover this from a backup?

PS I just did this; could not find anywhere how to do it, so I decided to add a question + answer for others. There are similar questions on this site, but none is about linux (except one which doesn't allow me to post an answer).

Answer (score 2):

Everything of a given 'person' is stored in `~/.config/chromium/Profile X` where the X is a number (a digit). To restore from backup:

1. Goto `chrome://settings/people` and make sure a person with the right name and email exists. Create a new one if it was entirely deleted.
2. Close all chromium browser windows. Make sure with `ps aux | grep chrom` that nothing is running anymore.
3. Go to `.config/chromium` in your BACKUP and find the deleted 'Profile X' directory. You can recognize it by looking at 'Profile X/Preferences' which will contain the name and email of the account used for that profile. Also, `Profile X/Google Profile Picture.png` should show the profile picture that you used.
4. Now that you know X, edit `BACKUP/.config/chromium/Local State` and `~/.config/chromium/Local State` and find the string "Profile X" in the former. It should look something like `"Profile 2":{"active_time":...`. Copy the string between that `{` and the matching closing brace `}`. The closing brace will be followed by a comma followed by the next Profile, or if it is the last one by another closing brace. In `~/.config/chromium/Local State` find the `"Profile Y":{...` that you want to fix (ie, the one you created at step 1; it will have the same name and email address thus. Lets say that the new profile is 'Profile 5' then you'd replace the `{...}` in `"Profile 5":{...}` with what you copied from your backed up Local State file under -say- `Profile 2` (if X was 2).
5. Delete the whole directory `Profile 5` (or whatever your new profile is), and copy `Profile 2` from your backup to `~/.config/chromium/Profile 5`.
6. Start chrome. It should say that chromium wasn't shut down cleanly and ask if you want to restore your session. Say Yes. You should get back *everything* - history, cookies, password, bookmarks, windows with all open tabs even.